# Array en angular tipo [object Object],[object Object]

Tags: angular, typescript

Al traer los datos directos de la bd me retorna
 `[object Object],[object Object]`

Mi consulta es la siguiente

```
      this.CotizacionService.listaPartidasPorIdCliente(this.data.id).subscribe(res => {
        this.listaInformacion = res
      });
    }
```

Al imprimir la variable `res`  me devuelve `(2) [{…}, {…}]`  mas sin embargo no se como poder acceder a cada uno de ellos hasta su propiedad como `res[0].id`  sin que sea mecánico  sino que pueda acceder a cada propiedad que contenga el array

Comment: Busca en Google como iterar un arreglo de objetos en javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una buena practica es crear interface con los datos que esperas recibir, es una ayuda incalculable porque no estas a ciegas.

ejemplo:
Tienes tu consulta, que va a tú servicio:

```
this.CotizacionService.listaPartidasPorIdCliente(this.data.id).subscribe(res => 
     {
        this.listaInformacion = res
      });
```

en tu servicio estas haciendo la consulta a tu backend:

```
import { Partidas} from '../interfaces/partidas.interfaces'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class PacientesService {
  private baseUrl: string = environment.apiUrl

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}


listaPartidasPorIdCliente(id:string):Observable<Partidas[]>{
return this.http.get<Partidas[]>(`${this.urlApi}/clientes/${id}`)
}

}
```

Ahora creas una interface de esta manera en un fichero con este nombre `partidas.interfaces.ts` donde incluyes todos los campos de tu repuesta

```
export interfaces Partidas{
id      : string;
clientes: string;
cantidad: number;
}
```

Esto es solo un ejemplo, con esto ya tienes en tu subscripcion de consulta a tu backend todo el tipado de la respuesta y te va a realizar el autocompletado cuando necesites acceder a cualquier elemento de tu respuesta.

Ahora en tu consulta y con el ejemplo de interface que creamos puedes acceder asi.

```
  this.CotizacionService.listaPartidasPorIdCliente(this.data.id).subscribe(res => {
            this.listaInformacion = res
            console.log(this.listadoInformacion.id) // ejemplo accediendo al id con tipado
          });
```

debes inicializar además en tu componente la variable `listaInformacion` asi:

```
listaInformacion!: Partidas[]
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda porque había echo otras cosas pero me parecía que no era muy practico, pero gracias a tu solución